# CMake Error: include could not find load file: targets

Tags: cmake, configuration, freertos, esp32

I'm trying to run AmazonFreeRTOS on my ESP32 (at Windows). After creating build folder in my amazon-freertos main folder I've tried to build it from main folder with

> cmake --build .\build

The Error I've got is

> include could not find load file: targets

However, there is a idf_functions.cmake file that contains `include(targets)` command, and the targets.cmake file is in the same folder so I don't know why the error occured.

Answer (score 4):

If you pay close attention to the error, you'd notice the full error says something like:

> CMake Error at
>   your-amazon-freertos-directory/vendors/espressif/esp-idf/tools/cmake/idf_functions.cmake: 26 (include)
>
> include could not find load file:
>
> targets

This is because `idf_functions.cmake` sets the variable `IDF_PATH` to `$ENV{IDF_PATH}` which was configured in `~/.profile` when the line `export IDF_PATH=~/esp/esp-idf` was added, as seen [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.1.5/get-started-cmake/add-idf_path-to-profile.html#linux-and-macos).

If you navigate to `~/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/` you'd notice that files like `target.cmake` and `ldgen.cmake`, which are being included `<your-amazon-freertos-directory>/vendors/espressif/esp-idf/tools/cmake/idf_functions.cmake`, do not exist.

**Solution 1 (somewhat hacky):**
Copy the contents of `<your-amazon-freertos-directory>/vendors/espressif/esp-idf/tools/cmake/` to `~/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/`

**Solution 2:**
Modify the ~/.profile file to add the following lines instead of that suggested in [the guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.1.5/get-started-cmake/add-idf_path-to-profile.html#linux-and-macos):
`export IDF_PATH=~/<your-amazon-freertos-directory>/vendors/espressif/esp-idf/`
`export PATH="$PATH:$IDF_PATH/tools"`

This should circumvent any CMake include errors during generation of build files and during build.

Answer (score 0):

Since Amazon FreeRTOS supports many different platforms in addition to ESP32, you might need to supply additional commands to tell CMake that ESP32 is the target you want to build.

Try using

```
cmake -DVENDOR=espressif -DBOARD=esp32_wrover_kit -DCOMPILER=xtensa-esp32 -S . -B your-build-directory
```

from your top level folder to generate your makefiles into the build folder, and then switching to your build folder and calling

```
make all
```

(From the "Build, Flash, and Run the Amazon FreeRTOS Demo Project" section of
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/getting_started_espressif.html)